# Error loading dataTFS.WebApi.Exception when performing an Enhanced Test Suite Export from Azure Dev Ops

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to export a test suite to Excel, from Azure Dev Ops Version Dev18.M170.6. I am using this menu item below, selecting `Enhanced Test Suite Export`

[image]

When the export dialog appears, I see a banner message

> Error loading dataTFS.WebApi.Exception: An undefined error occurred while attempting to connect to the server. Status code 0: .

and I can't proceed past this point.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Have you installed some extensions, and then you can export the test suite to Excel?

Comment: We have some extensions, but nothing around the Test Plans side. I can do a straight `.CSV` export, which I can live with for now.